# Installed CloudFlare Origin Certificates on Apache Server but certificate cannot be trusted

Tags: ssl, ubuntu-16.04, cloudflare

Installed an Origin Certificates on Apache Server but certificate cannot be trusted when I visit the domain. The certificate path says CloudFlare Origin Certificate. and the Certificate status says issuer of this certificate can not be found.

```
My ssl config
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.key
```

DNS section of the dashboard I selected DNS only on the domain record cause I want it to use the CloudFlare certificate with the extended expiry. When I add proxy only it will not use the Certificate I generated. Kindly advise